# UI-Router : State redirecting to first child on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am working on an AngularJS app using UI router with multiple named views. My app has one ui-view in index.html and states are configured as :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : "partials/login.html",
        controller : "login-controller"
    })
    .state("portal", {
        url :"",
        abstract : true,
        templateUrl : "partials/header.html",
    })
    .state("portal.create-claim", {
        url : "/dashboard",
        views : {
            'create-claim' : {
                    templateUrl : "partials/create-claim.html",
                    controller : "create-claim-controller"
            }
        }
    })
    .state("portal.history", {
        url : "/history",
        views : {
            'history' : {
                templateUrl : "partials/history.html",
                controller : "history-controller"
            }
        }
    })
    /*          Other child states          */
```

I am using angular material tabs in the header for navigation. Data specific to each tab is plugged in the named view provided in header.html, hence I have made "portal" state as abstract and "create-claim" and "history" state as its child states.

Now when I am on tab history, url is : http://localhost:8082/history and refresh the browser, app goes from portal.history to portal.create-claim state. I understand that Angular apps are SPA and page refreshing bootstraps entire app but before refresh, if the url was pointing to history state, then after refresh it should go to history state. I tried to debug using $stateChangeStart event. I found that app indeed goes to "portal.history" state but then immediately redirects to 'first child state' of abstract state i.e. "portal.create-claim". I confirmed this issue by making "portal.history" as first child and "portal.create-claim" as second child, then it goes to "portal.history" as the final redirected state.

I can't figure out the issue. I am trying to handle page refresh for my app. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you take the url config out of your abstract portal stare, does it make a difference?

Comment: have you tried my answer ?

Comment: @mindparse : No that won't make any difference. This is generally used so that all child states get their parent's url appended to their urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is kind of tricky but It is working. I just check with my own code.

Problem

The thing is whenever you `refresh` the page if the `view(html file)` contains `md-tabs` directive it will redirect to the 1st tab(0th index). Now these tabs have index starting from `0 to length-1`. So if you want a default tab to 3 you can use `md-selected` attribute of `md-tabs` directive but you are asking for setting this in a dynamic way based upon the URL.

So for that first we define a `$scope` variable in our main controller and assign that to `md-selected`. The main controller means the controller associated with `portal` state.If it does not exist then you need to define it.

Now If you are using `ui-view` for each tab and different URL that appropriate controller will be called each time.

Problem
So if you are not at your default index page and you refresh the page you will be redirected to default index but `ui-route's resolve` of that URL will be executed.
So you need to pass appropriate index to that main controller and for that we can use `service` since it is availabe appication-wide.

Example

first we define a service

```
var Session = function () {
    this.setIndex = function(index) {
        this.index = index;
    };

    this.getIndex = function() {
        return this.index ? this.index : 0 ;
    };
};

Session.$inject = [];
angular.module('tempApp').service('Session', Session);
```

routes file

```
.state("portal", {
    url :"/",
    templateUrl : "partials/header.html",
    controller: "TempController"
     resolve: {
               temp: function (Session) {
                Session.setIndex("0");
                }
              }

})
.state("portal.create-claim", {
    url : "dashboard",
    views : {
        'create-claim' : {
                templateUrl : "partials/create-claim.html",
                controller : "create-claim-controller",
                resolve: {
                           temp: function (Session) {
                                Session.setIndex("1");
                            }
                 }
        }
    }
})
.state("portal.history", {
    url : "history",
    views : {
        'history' : {
            templateUrl : "partials/history.html",
            controller : "history-controller",
            resolve: {
                           temp: function (Session) {
                                Session.setIndex("2");
                            }
                 }
        }
    }
```

view file:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="tabIndex">
    ....
</md-tabs>
```

TempController for that

```
var TempController = function (Session) {
    this.tabIndex = Session.getIndex();
};
TempController.$inject = ['Session'];
angular.module('tempApp').controller('TempController', TempController);
```

Comment: Sorry for not updating! You are right; when app restarts, angular material does not know which tab to select by default. So, either we can let it go to zeroth(default) state(which was happening in my case) or we can use md-selected. But there exists another alternative implementation which I actually used. Because each tab's content is populated inside named ui-view of header.html, we can set a property $scope.selectedIndex = 0 in portalController and for each child state we need to set $scope.$parent.selectedIndex = index_of_md-tab. Anyways, thanks for the help.